# No me lee la fuente

Tags: css, fuentes

Por que no me lee la fuente, si tengo la carpeta "/static/fonts/nombredefuente.ttf" y no me la lee, en la consola me aparece en rojo, pongo esa carpeta en la raiz, igual sigue haciendo lo mismo, asi tengo el css:

```html
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url('/static/fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-LightItalic';
    src: url('/static/fonts/OpenSansCondensed-LightItalic.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
    src: url('/static/fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Bold.ttf');
}

body {
 background: #fff;
 font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
}
```

Tengo el public_html, adentro una carpeta, llamada "carpeta1" y adentro, otra carpeta llamada "carpetaA" y adentro de "carpetaA" tengo el index, los css y las fuentes. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la fuente está adentro de "/fonts/" en el directorio principal, adentro de "public_html"

Comment: intenta sin la primera diagonal **'static/fonts/...'**

Comment: No, veo el link que me da la consola, y está PERFECTO, igual me lo pone en rojo

Comment: Hola MatiPHP, ¿qué es lo que te aparece en rojo en la consola? ¿Podrías compartir el mensaje? También, sería bueno que editaras la pregunta para añadir más información como por ejemplo el árbol de estructura de tu proyecto (donde se vea dónde están las fuentes y los archivos CSS).

Comment: Coloca tu directorio para poder ayudarte. Es problema de carpetas.

Comment: Como comentario aparte, no relacionado con el problema de la pregunta: ésta no es la mejor manera de importar fuentes a un proyecto. Es la misma fuente, sería mejor importarlas todas con el mismo nombre y especificando el peso/estilo en cada una de ellas. De ese modo no tienes que redefinir las fuentes para cada caso.

Comment: @MatiPHP solo para asegurarme, ¿en la edición indicas que las fuentes están en `/carpeta1/carpetaA/` mientras que en el código importas las fuentes de `/static/fonts/`?

Comment: Mira, ahi edito con una imagen para que veas

Comment: Listo, ahi agregue todo

Comment: Prueba asi entonces si tienes todo dentro de la misma carpeta @font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf');
}

Comment: No, y eso que esta donde me dice la consola de chrome, pero no la toma

Comment: Es la misma ruta, pero igual la pone en rojo

Comment: Coloca como te dije y limpia la cache luego prueba

Comment: Exactamente igual queda.

Comment: ¿ Te funciono ?

Comment: No, queda igual, la consola pone la misma ruta en donde está la fuente pero igual no la lee

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82489/discussion-between-oswuell-and-matiphp).

Comment: No encuentro solucion

Answer (score 0):

El estandar css desde su primera versión dice lo siguiente:

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style
>   sheet, not relative to the document.

Esto quiere decir que las rutas relativas están marcadas por el origen de la página de estilo, no del documento que las llama.

Sabiendo esto, debes tener en cuanta las siguientes observaciones para crear las rutas relativas.

[image: tabla creación url relativa]

Puedes echar un vistazo a un articulo completo en español (relativo a xhtml, pero aplica igualmente) en el siguiente enlace: [Enlaces relativos y absolutos](http://librosweb.es/libro/xhtml/capitulo_4/enlaces_relativos_y_absolutos.html)

**¿Y si aún así no funciona?**

**Recursos con error 404**

Prueba a acceder desde tu navegador introduciendo en la barra de dirección la ruta absoluta de la fuente:

```
http://midominio.com/ejemplo/carpeta/fuentes/fuente.ttf
```

Si no se puede acceder al recurso, comprueba la configuración de tu servidor para permitir el acceso al recurso.

**Recursos con otros errores 401, ...**
Debemos consultar el código de estado de respuesta si no lo conocemos, y configurar el servidor para permitir el acceso al recurso.

**Sin código de estado**

Si este pequeño experimento nos lanza la descarga de la fuente o recurso, debemos empezar a pensar que puede ser un error de seguridad. Esto se ve reflejado con el estado `cancelado` o `abortado` en los inspectores de red de los principales navegadores.

En estos casos es habitual encontrar mensajes en la consola de desarrollo advirtiendo que estamos realizado una acción no permitida,como puede ser el consumo de recursos de otro dominio diferente, conocido como `CORS (Cross Origins)`

En estos casos podemos considerar que estamos consumiendo un recurso de otro dominio diferente al nuestro, y nos encontraremos con que nuestro navegador está `abortando` la obtención del recurso.

En estos casos podemos considerar descargar el recurso y almacenarlo en nuestro servidor ( ¬¬ , si es nuestro claro... ) o permitir el origen cruzado en el servidor de destino.

Para eso encontramos numerosa información en la red sobre cómo activar CORS en los principales servidores.

Comment: Cuando abro la ventana en rojo, me salta para descargar la fuente, asi que eso esta bien.

Comment: Voy a actualizar la respuesta. Imagino que no es el caso, pero no estarás consumiendo una hoja css de un dominio diferente o ya publicada en tu host (internet) desde tu ordenador personal. ¿Verdad?

Comment: Cuando accedo al link, me salta para descargar la fuente